# Toolbar.getBackButton on Codename One

Tags: codenameone

To manipulate the BackButton after creating it with `.getToolbar().setBackCommand(...)`, I need to get it, so I create the following code:

```
public static final boolean isAndroidTheme = UIManager.getInstance().isThemeConstant("textComponentOnTopBool", false);
if (isAndroidTheme) {
  originalBackButton = this.getToolbar().getComponentAt(1);
} else {
  originalBackButton = this.getToolbar().getComponentAt(2);
}
```

It works, but I'm worried how much it is reliable. Is it possible to do better or is this code fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setBackCommand` either returns a command like this:

```
public Command setBackCommand(String title, ActionListener<ActionEvent> listener)
```

Or accepts a `Command` as the argument to the method. Once you have the command you can find the applicable component with `Button b = toolbar.findCommandComponent(cmd);`.